# csv import shows category does not exist for already existing categories

Tags: magento-1.8, import, csv

Am using Magento version 1.8.1. Created categories in admin and prepared the CSV file filling out all the categories for the products.

when importing am getting error "category does not exist in row .." when i checked the csv file the categories are all there. Checked for the case sensitivity too. I used find method in the browser and the categories are found.

**Import error**

[image: Import error]

**My categories in admin**

[image: Admin categories]

**My CSV file.**

[image: CSV file]

Please advice me to solve this issue. Thanks.

**UPDATE**
Saving the csv file to UTF-8 Solved the issue. But after that when i import, i get errors on other categories.
Some category rows in csv file are 
 **Apparel/Girls Clothes 2T - 4T/Dresses - Daywear** 
 **Madame Alexander/Supplements For Dolls/Doll Clothes 16" And Up**
I get category not exist where ever i have the (-),(") and numbers in category names in CSV.
Checked for the spaces and case-sensitivities and its all correct.
Please help me to solve this issue..

Comment: did you check your file encoding as being UTF-8(without BOM)?

Comment: you may missed any one value in this row or white spacing. check it

Comment: @JulienLachal Oh, i forgot that part. My csv was in ANSI and i changed it to UTF-8 and voila, the problem solved. Thanks for remaining.

Comment: @Marius :: The problem is still not yet resolved. Please see the update section in my question. Should i still answer it ?

Comment: Ah. Sorry. I didn't see the update. I think you should wait a bit more.

Comment: did you make sure these are spaces and not non-breanking spaces? same goes for dash (-)

Comment: @JulienLachal :: yes i did it. I have copied the category names and searched for it in the browser and its found. Did it for the parent categories also. The spaces in the category names are not breaking spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially My CSV file was in ANSI encoding format. Saving the CSV file to UTF-8 encoding Solved the issue. 

But after that when i import, i get errors on other categories. **WHICH WAS DUE TO SPACING BETWEEN THE SLASHES SEPARATING THE CATEGORIES.**
I Looked for the Case-sensitivity and fixed few and now all the products are imported, Even if my category name contains (-) (") and numbers.
Thank you.

Comment: Hate spaces lol. Glad you fixed it yourself, please accept your answer so as this question is marked as solved.

Comment: @JulienLachal :: Yeah. Thanks to you for the initial heads up on UTF-8. I can only accept my answer tomorrow. I got alert like that when i tried to do.